# CRM: Error Mapping Users

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

> TL;DR Empty User Mapping Dialog in Deployment Manager Organisation Import

I need to change OS from Windows 2008 R2 (#1) to Windows 2012 (#2) for my CRM 2013 machine, leaving crm unchanged. Etc for SQL server machine.
What I do:

1. Disable organisation in Deployment Manager on #1 machine.
2. Detach database in SQL Server.
3. Copy .mdf and .lds files of my organisation to new SQL Server machine.
4. Attach database on that machine.
5. In Deployment Manager on #2 machine I click import organisation and
   importing organisation.

The problem arises at Edit User Mappings Screen. It doesn't matter which option I chose (Auto map, Manual map, etc)

[image]

cmdmsnapin.log shows me that Exception.

```
15:05:48|  Error| Exception occurred while mapping usersMicrosoft.Crm.CrmArgumentException: 
Expected non-empty string. ---> System.ArgumentException: Expected non-empty string.
Parameter name: domainAndAccount
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Crm.Exceptions.ThrowIfEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Crm.UserManagement.DomainAccount..ctor(String domainAndAccount)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.DBImportHelper.ReadUsers(IProgressEventSource progressHandler, 
UserAccountMapper mapUserAccountInfo, String sqlServerName, String databaseName)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportUserMapper.MapUsers()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UserMappingProgressPage.PerformUserMapping()
```

Why such may happen?

Comment: check SystemUserBase for empty Domain fields, and fill out the blanks: it should fix the issue

Comment: @Alex, if it should fix the issue, why you don't write it as Answer?

Comment: By the way, this solved my problem, so, please, can you write as Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the `SystemUserBase` table in the organization you are importing, and making sure all users have the Domain correctly populated should fix the issue.